# An equality of discriminant and resultant divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let $\Phi$ be the root system of a split group $G$ over a field $k$. The differentials $d\alpha$ of the roots define a polynomial called the discriminant
$$\prod_{\alpha\in\Phi}d\alpha$$
on $\mathfrak t$, the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. The polynomial is invariant under the action of the Weyl group, and gives a function on $\mathfrak c=\text{Spec}(k[\mathfrak t]^W)$. The divisor $\mathfrak D_G$ of this polynomial is called the *discriminant divisor*.

If $H$ is a split subgroup of $G$ equal to a centralizer of a semisimple element of $G$, there is a morphism
$$\nu:\mathfrak c_H=\mathfrak t_H/W\to\mathfrak c=\mathfrak t/W$$
that comes from an isomorphism of Cartan subalgebras $\mathfrak t_H\to\mathfrak t$ and an inclusion of Weyl groups $W_H\subset W$.

The claim is that there exists a *resultant divisor* $\mathfrak R$ defined by
$$\prod_{\alpha\in\Psi}d\alpha$$
where $\Psi$ is the subset of positive roots in $\Phi-\Phi_H$ such that the following is true:
$$\nu^*\mathfrak D_G=\mathfrak D_H+2\mathfrak R$$
This claim is made in [Ngo B.C., 1.10.3](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0446) but I don't see how the proof of it works.